# Optimize duplicated function with different parameter

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

I have two exact the same functions and one different function which take a `TypeX` as parameter. All `TypeX` has the same parent class `Type`. The dummy code is like:

```
public void Append(TypeA item) { //same code }
public void Append(TypeB item) { //same code }
public void Append(TypeC item) { //different code }
```

I wonder is there a good way to optimize such functions? My code needs to pick up the right function based on the class type, so I can't use the parent class or a generic type here because that will affect `TypeC`'s engagement.

The best thing would be `public void Append(TypeA item || TypeB item)` but of course there's no such a thing available. Any idea?

Comment: You can use the parent class, then create a more specific overload for `TypeC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas the solutions offered by @erwin-bolwidt would work, I suggest you also consider

```
private void baseAppend (TypeParent item) { //same code }
public void Append(TypeA item) { baseAppend (item); }
public void Append(TypeB item) { baseAppend (item); }
public void Append(TypeC item) { //different code }
```

This method would allow a looser coupling and the potential for specialised logging and expansion in the future

Comment: For function baseAppend(), I need to pass in the parent class Type to make both TypeA and TypeB accepted, right?

Comment: or its interface

Answer (score 1):

Methods to be called are selected at compile time based on the declared type (not the actual type) of the object. It's safe to merge Append for TypeA and TypeB into one method that takes an argument of `Type item` - it doesn't make a difference from the current code.

But if you want to select on actual type, you need to use `instanceof`. Or you create a method on type that returns whatever you need in the `append` method.

```
public void append(Type item) {
    if (item instanceof TypeC) {
        // Do TypeC-specific stuff
    } else {
        // Do stuff for TypeA, TypeB, and any other subtype of Type
    }
}
```

Or cleaner, if the only difference is in what you get from the item:

```
public class Type {
    public X getWhateverYouWantToAppend() {
        // Return stuff for TypeA, TypeB, and any other subtype of Type
    }
}

public class TypeC extends Type {
    public X getWhateverYouWantToAppend() {
        // Return stuff for TypeC specifically
    }
}

public class YourOtherClass {
    public void append(Type item) {
        X thingToAppend = item.getWhateverYouWantToAppend();
        // Do the appending
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent class for `TypeA` and `TypeB`. Then use this type as an argument to the overloaded function.

This way you can avoid a duplication of code.

Another way is to let these classes to implement some interface then use this interface as an argument to the overloaded function.

Third, you can use generic type and delegate implementation to corresponding functions.

Answer (score 0):

its simple in java, you can do it using method overloading

```
public class example{

public static void print(String s) {
    System.out.println("string - "+s);
}

public static void print(int q) {
    System.out.println("number - "+q);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    print(12);
    print("welcome");
}
}
```

output

```
number - 12
string - welcome
```